# How often I Can Update my Application on App Store?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, store

How often I can update mobile application on App Store? Can I update every 2-3 days?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? (There's most likely a better way than spamming the app store review team.) :-)

Comment: Can anyone provide a more up-to-date answer to this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Highly unlikely.

Apple's review time for a completely acceptable app update varies from less than 2 days to over 2 weeks, and a developer has no control over that length of time.  That will limit the rate of updating any app to Apple's pace.  Trying to update more often than this will put your update back at the end of the queue and slow down your approvals, and thus App store releases even more.

Somewhere, maybe a developer's talk, they may have recommended non-critical (for bugs) updates no more often than once per month.

For more frequent updates of content, see Apple's WWDC 2010 video on data driven app design, and consider having the app update certain content from your web site.

Comment: I tried searching for "Apple's WWDC 2010 video on data driven app design" on Google and the WWDC site, can't seem to find a video related to what you're talking about. Any idea what the name of the video is?

Answer (score 4):

Not really.

It usually takes Apple 7 days to review an app and if you upload a new update before the old one has been reviewed you go to the back of the queue. If you need to update your app more frequently than every ~7 days you should look into setting up a web-based update mechanism. Obviously, you won't be able to update any code this way, but you can update content as much as you like.

Comment: You were 19 seconds faster ;-)

Comment: What minimum time interval could be between app updates after application was already submitted to AppStore?

Comment: @Sergio no minimum time interval, though, like @GorillaPatch said in a comment below, frequent updates are annoying. Constant updates are the #1 reason that I delete apps off my phone.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot change it every 2-3 days, because there can be only one version in review of a given application. If a binary is submitted for review and you upload a new version, the old binary is thrown away and the review process starts over with the new version.

So you loose your position in the review queue each time you submit a new binary while the old one is already submitted but not accepted yet.

Comment: GorillaPatch, After approving by Apple my update can I provide new binary immediately?

Comment: Yes. When the application reaches the status __Ready for Sale__ you can upload the next release. But also think about the users. They can easily get annoyed by too many updates to fix a non-mature application. I would try to plan my release cycle better to deliver mature applications which require as few updates to fix things as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, yes. But take into consideration, that it will take some time for your applications to be reviewed by Apple.

Comment: Sandro Meier, do you have any official information(from Apple) about this point?

Comment: What do you mean by official information? I'm a developer and I developed a few apps by myself. So I can only say, that the duration of the review process is very different. Sometimes it takes about 2 day but I also waited about 14 days... But I cannot imagine a situation, where you have to update your code so frequently. If it is only the content you need to change, do it via the internet.